# Parcelable Fragment в другую Активность сохранив всё состояние

Tags: android, android-parcelable

Похожих вопросов много, но механизма я полностью не понимаю. У меня есть TabLayout,  в нем фрагменты, в которых уже сделаны действия такие как выбор радиокнопок и так далее. Я у ViewPager получаю экземпляры этих фрагментов и хочу передать их в другую активность.  Фрагменты имеют презентеры, в котором хранятся другие объекты. Моя цель в новой активности отобразить эти фрагменты сохранив состояние(если была нажата кнопка и вместо неё появился текст, а кнопка удалена, то все это должно сохраниться).  Я должен просто реализовать интерфейст Parcelable , сохранить в него   поля и передать в другую активность и этого достаточно? А как же тогда экземпляр презентера, наверняка он тоже должен реализовать интерфейс Parceleble . В общем не понимаю я как передать полностью всё состояние фрагмента. 
 Первым делом вы спросите а нафига это нужно и ответом на этот вопрос будет долгий рассказ о тонкостях дизайна этого приложения, поэтому не стоит об этом спрашивать.

Comment: Кажется, что Parcelable тут вообще не годится, т.к. куча объектов внутри, которые тоже должны реализовать интерфейс.  Я думал будет просто, передал экземпялр фрагмента и он будет иметь доступ к своему презентору  и т.д.

Comment: если появилась такая задача, как передать фрагмент со всем состоянием между активити, то видимо здесь нужно говорить не о тонкостях дизайна, а о отсутсутствии заранее проработанной архитектуры проекта и вообще слабом понимании, что и как работает в андроид. но это лирика. По факту вы не можете передать фрагмент со всем состоянием между активити никаким разумным способом, можно подумать о отдельном сингелтоне - менеджере фрагментов, но это будет костыль, подпирающий другой костыль.

Comment: По хорошему нужно менять архитектуру, если используемая завела вас в такой тупик, но делать этого вы видимо не будете. наиболее безболезненно такое можно решить сохраняя динамические изменения фрагмента в независимое хранилище (какие то флаги: какая кнопка нажата, какой текст введен и тд) и потом в другом экземпляре такого же фрагмента востанавливая по ним, но это тоже хрень будет лютая

Comment: Ясно. Беда. Архитектуру можно подправить, только в какую бы сторону, делов еше много не натворил. Сейчас опишу что хочу получить

Comment: pavlofff, В TabLayout есть с десяток фрагментов, вопросы с вариантами ответов и так далее. требуется: При ответе на все вопросы,выводится новая активность с двумя кнопками, одна показывает только те табы в которых ошибки , другая все табы.  До этого момента, наверно можно просто PageAdapter подправить чтобы мог скрывать ненужные табы. НО нужно чтобы когда мы нажали на ПОказать табы с ошибками и далее жмем на кнопку Back вернуться на активность с предложением показать все табы

Comment: Есть такое приложение. я хотел повторить дизайн. Там при нажатии на Мои ошибки выводится Tablayout с нужными табами и с анимацией как будто это новая активность. Вот я и подумал, что фрагменты передаются в новую активность

Comment: pavlofff, насчет предложения сохранять флаги: так ведь у меня есть Moxy , который сохранил все команды к этому фрагменту. Но все равно надо же этот ViewState передать..в общем жесть получается. Я надеялся тупо конвертировал фрагмент в массив байтов и передал и все ок.

Comment: как хранится все это, вопросы, ответы, что выбрал пользователь, где были ошибки и тд? просто в состоянии фрагмента, ни в какую бд не пишется?

Comment: Вопрос , ответы в презентере,  а всё остальные манипуляции пользователя в виде команд, а не флагов, хранятся в классе ViewState. Вы наверно не знаете про фреймворк Moxy раз спрашиваете.  С его помощью новая вью приаттаченная к презентеру принимает все команды , которые поступали из презентера. Теперь если учитывать что при появлении новой активности, презентеры всех табов живы..брр в общем плохой подход получается.

Comment: Просто в этом приложении явно видно, что появляется новая активность и по нажатию Показать табы с ошибми Появляется еще одна активность (анимация Справа приходит активность) . Показываются табы  и теперь если нажать кнопку Back возвращаюсь на активность с предложением показать табы с ошибками.

Comment: По другому ведь это не реализовать не передав фрагменты с состоянием. В общем похожая реализация есть в приложении https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.reactivephone.pdd.lite&hl=ru

Comment: хранить какие то динамические состояния, которые могут потребоваться за пределами вью в самом вью (хоть с мокси ) - хреновая практика. нужно использовать БД (или другое независимое внешнее хранилище) куда писать все важное ( какой ответ выбран, что введено и подрбное) и потом читать оттуда в любом месте, где потребуется. нужно разделить визуальное отображение и данные.  визуальные отображения вообще не передаются за пределы их непосредственного использования, только данные

Comment: pavlofff, я смог найти выход:  первая активность с табами вызывает вторую, во второй при нажатии на кнопку вызывается  Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT, т.е. вторая активность уйдет назад, а первая вернется на верх да еще и интент получит с информацией Что делать (показать табы с ошибками). Теперь жму кнопку назад (переопределил) вызывается интент с тем же флагом, появляется 
 вторая активность (единственный минус анимация такая как будто-то новая активность вызвалась, а мне нужна обратная анимация, есть флаг отключить анимацию вообще, но что то эффекта не увидел с первого раза)

Comment: Во второй активность кнопка Back выполняет intent c FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP , т.е. я удаляю из back stack обе активности и ухожу на  предшевствующую этим двум.

Comment: И не надо никуда фрагменты с состояниями передавать) надо теперь адаптер настроить так чтобы указанные табы можно было скрывать и возвращать, надеюсь граблей тут уже нет )

Comment: что будет, когда ваше приложение уйдет в фон (например пользователь захочет в вотсапе ответить) и потом будет опять открыто? с немалой долей вероятности все текущее состояние будет потеряно и вообще, эти манипуляции со стеком .. есть надежные проверенные решения, но это ваша программа конечно

Comment: Ну неет, я хоть не на столько то и новичек) ни одна из моих активностей не теряет свое состояние при сворачивании и даже при повороте экрана, т.к.  состояние TextView и RadioButton хранит сама система, а факт нажата ли кнопка (и теперь удалена) хранит Moxy, т.е. когда активность перевернется  Мокси нанизывает эти команды на вью.